# Create a mysql function in Joomla install.sql

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm trying to create a mysql function in the install.sql when installing a component. The function starts like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `dm`;

CREATE FUNCTION `dm`(st VARCHAR(55)) RETURNS varchar(128) CHARSET utf8
    NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE length, first, last, pos, prevpos, is_slavo_germanic SMALLINT;
  DECLARE pri, sec VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE ch CHAR(1);
...
```

It is pretty long so the full version you can find here:
https://github.com/AtomBoy/double-metaphone/blob/master/metaphone.sql

I have found this question:
[Create a mysql function while installing a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351220/create-a-mysql-function-while-installing-a-component)

But i already removed the delimiters and still get this error when installing the component:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 SQL=CREATE FUNCTION `dm`(st VARCHAR(55)) RETURNS varchar(128) CHARSET utf8 NO SQL BEGIN DECLARE length, first, last, pos, prevpos, is_slavo_germanic SMALLINT;
SQL =
CREATE FUNCTION `dm`(st VARCHAR(55)) RETURNS varchar(128) CHARSET utf8
    NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE length, first, last, pos, prevpos, is_slavo_germanic SMALLINT;
```

The DB error code is 1064.